# Stored procedure fulltext search

Tags: c#, sql-server, full-text-search

Can I have some help with next:

My c# app calls for sql stored procedure, and passes some search term (string containing multiple words).

```
    public List<ZapisModel> GetZapis_FullText(string Parametar)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SQLConn.CnnVal(Program.db)))
        {
            var output = connection.Query<ZapisModel>("dbo.spZapis_GetByTest_FTC @parametar", new { parametar = Parametar }).ToList();
            return output;
        }
    }
```

Sql stored procedure should take that passed parameter, and do a fulltext search with each word from string. I want to enable user to search for ALL words from string, for ANY word from string, so that is why I need to split string, and include each word in search using AND or OR, based on user preferences.

Also I would like this job entirely done in stored procedure.So app passes search term, stored procedure processes it, and returns search result.

Comment: why do you want to parse the search term in stored procedure? Isn't it easier to parse it and convert to FTS syntax using C#? There are help classes out there which already do this.

Comment: Can you show me how, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't parse your search criteria string at SQL procedure level. Instead, prepare the correct FTS search string using C#. In my projects I use a small (just 2 files) freeware library called EasyFTS.

Here is the EasyFTS project page on GitHub: https://github.com/SoftCircuits/FullTextSearchQuery

The syntax is very easy:

```
var fts = new EasyFts();
var orignalNonFTSEnabledQueryString = "Center Neck Spray Bottle";
var ftsEnabledsearchText = fts.ToFtsQuery(orignalNonFTSEnabledQueryString).
```

The above code will convert the normal non-FTS-enabled search string eg. `Center Neck Spray Bottle` to the FTS-enabled version like:

```
"(((FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Center) AND FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Neck)) AND FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Spray)) AND FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Bottle))"
```

which you can use in the [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql)/[CONTAINSTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql) or [FREETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/freetext-transact-sql)/[FREETEXTTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/freetexttable-transact-sql) clauses.

Theare many configuration options for the EasyFTS class. You can have it general FTS query strings with words separated by `AND` or `OR`. Just examine their docs.

This article contains very thorough description of EasyFTS: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/data/easy-full-text-search-queries .

**Disclaimer:** I'm not the author of the EasyFTS library.

HTH

Comment: @leroy You're welcome! Thanks for the answer accept!

Comment: Lets say I want to change search from AND to OR (to search for ANY of the  input words). How can it be done?

Comment: @leroy you need break your input string into words using `string.Split`, then construct a new string with ` or ` inserted between words, then send it to EasyFTS parser. It should be this case from examples: `abc or def ==> (FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, abc) OR FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, def))` .